# Using $.Ajax to GET, Update & PUT JSON back on the server when button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

**I Need help to merge GET & PUT into a single function**

I'm looking to write some JQuery that gets executed when a button is clicked. What i want to do, is using AJAX... go and get a JSON file from the server, look up a value in it, change the value, and then PUT it back to the server.

E.g.

- The JSON contains a lists of Jobs Ads, and within that a list of candidates for that Ad.
- The HTML PHP basically just looks up the JSON, and then does a loop to output the Status & Name of each candidate.
- I also included a button with each record that toggles on-click (change text and class) to indicate whether a candidate is suitable or not.
- As part of the on-click event, i also want to update the JSON on the server by changing the 'status' of that candidates record from 'active' to 'inactive' or vice versa.

Note: I'm not looking to refresh the page at all... i'd like it all to happen in the background.

---

I've found quite a few examples of how to do to the individual $.ajax bits (e.g. GET, PUT etc), but i can't seem to put it all together...

JSON:

```
{
    "ads": 
        [{
            "id": "12345678",
            "hirername": "Demo Bar",
            "candidates": 
                [{
                    "status": "active",
                    "name": "Gregory Jones",
                    "dist": "Richmond (4km away)",
                    "exp1": "Barman at City Bar for 2 years",
                    "avail1": "Mon to Fri - Morning, Evening & Night",
                    "visa": "Australian Citizen",
                    "call": "0413451222"
                },
                {
                    "status": "active",
                    "name": "Jackie Linton",
                    "dist": "Box Hill (13km away)",
                    "exp1": "Bar girl at Collins Bar for 1 year",
                    "avail1": "Mon to Fri - Morning & Evening",
                    "visa": "Working holiday visa",
                    "call": "0413456555"
                }]
        }]
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        // Bind click event on all the buttons inside .card
        $(".card button").click(function() {

            // Check if the clicked button has class `btn_s`
            if ($(this).hasClass('btn_s')) {

                // Update the button text & class (styling)
                $(this).html('<font style="color: #666;">Marked as not suitable. </font>Undo?').toggleClass('btn_s notsu');

                // Define the URL
                var URL = "test.json";
                // Get the Json
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(result) {
                        // Step 1: Find the value of 'status' within the JSON for the applicable record. (lookup by name)

                        // Step 2: Change the value of status - Toggle between 'active' and 'inactive'

                        // Step 3. Save the JSON changes - PUT back to the server.
                    }
                });

            }   else {

                // Update the button text & class (styling)
                 $(this).html('Mark as not suitable?').toggleClass('notsu btn_s');

                // Define the URL
                var URL = "test.json";
                // Get the Json
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(result) {
                        // Step 1: Find the value of 'status' within the JSON for the applicable record. (lookup by name)

                        // Step 2: Change the value of status - Toggle between 'active' and 'inactive'

                        // Step 3. Save the JSON changes - PUT back to the server.
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP/HTML (the button):

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $json = json_decode($json, true);

        foreach ($json['ads'] as $ad){  

            foreach($ad['candidates'] as $data){
                echo '<div class="card">';
                echo '<b>Status: </b>';
                echo '<span id="status">' . $data['status'] . '</span><br>';
                echo '<b>Name: </b>';
                echo '<span>' . $data['name'] . '</span><br>';
                echo '<br><button class="btn_s" name ="' . $data['name'] . '" id="un_btn" >Mark as inactive?</button>';
                echo '</div><br>';
            }
        }
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Cheers,
Rob.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Rayon - Is there anything specific about my question that you think i could do better?

Comment: Thanks... is this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, consider setting an ID for the candidates.

Set a "data-id" and a "data-status" attributes to the button and then just call a url with that.
ie:

PHP (the line that generates the button)

```
echo '<br><button data-id="'. $data['id'].'" data-status="'. $data['status'].'" class="btn_s" name ="' . $data['name'] . '" id="un_btn" >Mark as inactive?</button>';
```

Script:

```
$(".card button").click(function() {
    var isactive=$(this).data("status") == "active";
    var cid=$(this).data("id");
    var URL = "setstatus.php"; 
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        data: {active: isactive,id:cid},
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            // Set the row as active/inactive.
        }
    });
}
```

The file setstatus.php will be called with the params like this: `setstatus.php?active=true&id=23`
Then you can update the value of that candidate into the database and return a json with a confirmation (or not!)